# Can software written for windows be used on linux?

Tags: windows-7

we have programs at work that I would like to use on my linux laptop, is there a shell program i can run to be able to use them or must i have a dual boot system, limited HD space.
Regards
Gavin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its called wine you get it by sudo apt-get install wine you will need to have the 32 bit library's then you do sudo wine windowsexe.exe

Comment: Welcome to AU! Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/524431/edit) your answer to include some form of punctuation to visually separate and structure your sentences. I had to read it three times to get what you mean. You can also [format code sections](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to use a fixed width font stand out from the other text. :-]